# Upload Image with deep parameters in Alamofire

Tags: swift, file-upload, parameter-passing, alamofire, multipartform-data

How to upload image with this kind parameters in Alamofire

```
{
    "user_email":"johndoe@yopmail.com",
    "user_token":"yiDmaVs6Ax-zUj1cM-Eh",
    "claim_id": 6,
    "items":[{
        "name":"Watch",
        "name_of_owner": "Selena Gomez",
        "phone_of_owner": "091237462",
        "email_of_owner": "selenagomez@gmail.com",
        "quantity":1,
        "is_owned": false, 
        "photo":"image data here..."
    },{
        "name":"iMac",
        "name_of_owner": "Steff Gomez",
        "phone_of_owner": "091237462",
        "email_of_owner": "selenagomez@gmail.com",
        "quantity":1,
        "is_owned": false,
        "photo": "image data here..."
    }]

}
```

If you think this is not the best practice on how we should handle image upload for each item. pls enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var bannerImage = [[String:AnyObject]]()
    var fileIDSArr = [String]() // these are how many images you want to load
    for i in 0..<fileIDSArr.count
    {
        let imageId:String = fileIDSArr[i]
        bannerImage.append([ "name":"Watch" as AnyObject,
                             "name_of_owner": "Selena Gomez" as AnyObject,
                             "phone_of_owner": "091237462" as AnyObject,
                             "email_of_owner": "selenagomez@gmail.com" as AnyObject,
                             "quantity":1 as AnyObject,
                             "is_owned": false as AnyObject,
                             "photo":"image data here..." as AnyObject])
    }
   
    var params = [String:Any]()
    params = ["user_email":"johndoe@yopmail.com",
              "user_token":"yiDmaVs6Ax-zUj1cM-Eh",
              "claim_id": 6,
              "items":bannerImage]
```

Comment: How are we going to append that nested params in multipartFormData? 
(e.g) multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!, withName: "\(key)[logo]", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")